# How do you integrate using a normal function instead of an Inline function?

Tags: undefined, octave, integral

I'm trying to figure out how to do an integral in Octave. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong (or if it's an issue with Octave). I can do the integral with an inline function, but not with a normal function (see the following). When using the normal function Octave throws `error: 't' undefined near line 8 column y`. Line 8 is `result = 2*t.^2 +5*t;` in the code snippet below.

```
% Inline function (can use to integrate)
fn1 = @(t) 2*t.^2 +5*t;

% Normal function (can't use to integrate)
function result = fn2(t)
  result = 2*t.^2 +5*t;
end

% integrate using Inline function (works)
integral(fn1,0,15)

% integrate using Normal function (doesn't work)
integral(fn2,0,15)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several things that are wrong in what you say (including the statement that octave was built to support matlab :p )

You are conflating the concepts of 'normal' (i.e. file-based) functions, with inline functions, with function handles, and anonymous functions. These are all fairly basic concepts in octave (and matlab). And for what it's worth, matlab and octave are identical in this respect.

Here is the relevant part of the manual. It may look like a lot, but each link is actually fairly short and worth reading.

https://octave.org/doc/v5.2.0/Functions-and-Scripts.html#Functions-and-Scripts

The bit that would interest you most in this question is section 11.11 dealing with function handles and anonymous functions.

I will attempt to explain briefly below, but it's well worth reading the manual.

Effectively, the expression `@(t) 2*t.^2 +5*t;` creates an 'anonymous function', and returns a 'function handle'. `fn1 = @(t) 2*t.^2 +5*t;` therefore captures the created function handle in the variable `fn1`. This means you can use the handle to call the underlying function it represents, as `fn1( t )`, or pass it as an argument to functions.

Normal functions on the other hand, are typically defined in their own .m files. This makes them available to call, but not to pass as variables. If you want to pass an existing m-file function as a variable to another function, you need to create a handle first. E.g. if you have a function called `myfunction`, you can do `myhandle = @myfunction`. After this you can pass `myhandle` into functions, or even call it as `myhandle()`, to call the underlying function that it represents (i.e. `myfunction`).

---

<sub>PS. Inline functions are a different thing (you create a function from a string), and are not worth discussing since they are being deprecated by both matlab and octave.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Using `integral(@fn2,0,15)` will work. Though I still don't understand why the `@` is necessary in this context.

Comment: The `@` is necessary because `fn2` is the same as `fn2()`.